# ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname, pip, windows

Tags: python, pip

```
File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
return ssl_wrap_socket(
File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket
ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock) 
File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1027, in _create
raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

Whatever I am trying - pip returns the same error message. And I am having a hard time tracking down the cause of this problem.

Environment: Windows 10 (latest build), Proxy.
Proxy is set (also in the variables). And it works. Moreover, i wrote a simple python program retrieving the web page using urllib's request - and it works over this proxy server.

I've tried to force proxy in pip via command line, i've tried to use all these trusted-host parameters - everything fails. I reinstalled python directly from the web page. Nothing.

What's stranger - the very same proxy works flawlessly on linux systems. F.e. command:

```
pip3 install panda --proxy http://192.168.100.30:8088
```

Does work on Linux (same subnet, same proxy, same firewall), but fails on each Windows (i've tried the other systems) i try. This would mean that I am still missing some proxy settings on the Windows machine. But which? And why requests within python environment have no issues at all with the proxy?

Comment: Different `pip --version` on both systems?

Comment: Good point. I Upgraded the version on linux. 21.3.1. Still works. On WIndows I have version from installer - 21.2.3. Can't upgrade becase of the problem mentioned above. But this difference should be an issue.

Comment: Upgrade `pip` via a wheel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68945239/7976758

Comment: Strange. I did upgrade via wheel. Now I do have the same version, but different error: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002BED44E9750>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/django/

Comment: `getaddrinfo` -> temporary DNS problems?

Comment: That's what I thought, but oddly no problems at all using web pages, downloading pages using urllib, also many other package managers work fine. I use the very same DNS settings on my linux machines. But I'll try to dig in this direction. Anyway I was able to install what I needed using downloaded wheels, so i'ts not so urgent anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Run the same command `pip3 install panda --proxy http://192.168.100.30:8088` on windows, but before that, make sure no proxy is selected. You can do that by going to `Internet Explorer >> Settings >> Internet Options >> Connections >> Lan Settings` and unchecking all three checkboxes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error(pip, windows).

> ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname

For those of you who have your VPN turned on, try to close the VPN and run the same command again. This solved my problem. Hope this helps